# OAuth 2.0 on Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, kotlin, google-photos

I would like to create a simple app to check the abilities of newly launched Google Photos Library API (https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started).
However I am facing an 401 error when trying to get album list. I've enabled photos library API in API Console, and in my app I've requested access to this scope using the following code:

```
    val GOOGLE_PHOTOS_SCOPE = Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly")
    if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(
                    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                    GOOGLE_PHOTOS_SCOPE)) {
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this,
                1,
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                GOOGLE_PHOTOS_SCOPE)
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Permission granted")

        (application as QuizApp).photosLibraryApi.getAlbumList().enqueue(
                object: retrofit2.Callback<ResponseBody> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, t: Throwable?) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "FAIL ${t.toString()}", t)
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, response: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Success ${response.toString()}")
                    }

                }
        )
    }
```

I guess I need to somehow provide my client_id and project_id from credentials.json file, but I have no idea how to do it. Anyone done it before? Any tips what's the best way to do Google's OAuth2.0?

Answer (score 0):

After loggin in with the Google account (and this is async operation, so you need a listener - see Google login docs) you can get an authorisation code. This code you need to exchange for an access token, and this access token is then passed as a parameter to all your Google Photos API calls.
I just used a library like OKHTTP (on Android) to build the api request to get this accesstoken and yes, there you need your client key.
Note: JAVA code, but you can of course do the same in Kotlin with different syntax.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
                .add("client_id", CLIENT_AUTH_KEY_WEB)
                .add("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET)
                .add("redirect_uri", "")
                .add("code", ACTUAL AUTHORISATION CODE AFTER LOGIN)
                .build();
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
```

After this (and you need to have the listeners on for success or failure - see OKHTTP docs) then you can use the access token to get access to the API. 
Of course it should also work with RetroFit as I see you are using, but I have no experience with that library.